# Casting JArray to Dynamic[] so NEST's IndexMany works

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

### Problem description

I need to receive JSON array of objects (with almost any shape) and store them to ES database using function `IndexMany` (or some similar bulk indexing function). I found some clumsy solution with one drawback - it doesn't set `_id` property in ES correctly (according to the `id` property in JSON object).

And also I would like to know if there is any more elegant way how to achieve my goal without casting every JArray item to string and back to ExpandoObject.

#### Additional info

Elasticsearch DB 7.5.1
NEST (7.6.1)
Newtonsoft.Json (12.0.3)

### TLDR

Is there any elegant solution of following code:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")).DefaultIndex("people");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
            
// this string represents incoming JSON message
string json = @"[
    {
        ""id"": ""1"",
        ""name"": ""Andrej"",
        ""surname"": ""Burak"",
        ""dob"": ""1921-11-10T00:00:00+00:00""
    },
    {
        ""id"": ""2"",
        ""name"": ""Franta"",
        ""surname"": ""Dobrota"",
        ""dob"": ""1933-10-05T00:00:00+00:00""
    },
    {
        ""id"": ""3"",
        ""name"": ""Milos"",
        ""surname"": ""Ovcacek"",
        ""dob"": ""1988-05-05T00:00:00+00:00""
    }
]";


JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

foreach (var jtoken in jArray)
{
    var jobj = (JObject)jtoken;
    jobj.Add("DbCreated", JToken.FromObject(DateTime.UtcNow));
    jobj.Add("DbCreatedBy", JToken.FromObject("authors name"));
}

//working, but seems to me a bit too clumsy to convert every item to string and then back to dynamic object
var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic[] dlst = jArray.Select(t => (dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(t.ToString(), converter)).ToArray();

//not working cast 
dynamic[] dlstNW = jArray.ToObject<dynamic[]>();
            
var indexManyResponse = client.IndexMany(dlst); //working partially (but not using ID as index)
var indexManyResponseNotWorking = client.IndexMany(jArray); //not working
var indexManyResponseNotWorking2 = client.IndexMany(dlstNW); //not working


// expected behavior
dynamic[] jsondyn = new dynamic[]
{
    new { Id = "1", Name = "foo" },
    new { Id = "2", Name = "bar" },
    new { Id = "3", Name = "baz" },
};
var indexManyResponseWithIndex = client.IndexMany(jsondyn); //working perfectly, but don't know how to acieve this
```

Comment: It looks like your main problem is you're fighting with the way the NEST high-level client expects the `Id` property to look. Have you tried instructing the NEST client to index the documents by the `id` property instead? Or using the low-level client? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819542/index-json-document-using-elasticsearch-nest-c-sharp

Comment: Well, even if I change it to `Id` in JSON, it still doesn't work. I can use `client.Bulk(bulk => bulk.IndexMany(dlst, (b, d) => b.Id((Id)d.Id ))` but then if `Id` is missing or lowercased, it fails. It seems that I am going to need low-level client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [@gnud pointed me to low-level client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083126/casting-jarray-to-dynamic-so-nests-indexmany-works?noredirect=1#comment108065322_61083126) I think I have found my answer. Important thing is to build request manually [like it was explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48755143/2972326).

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")).DefaultIndex("people").DisableDirectStreaming();
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
            
// this string represents incoming JSON message
string json = @"[
    {
        ""id"": ""1"",
        ""name"": ""Andrej"",
        ""surname"": ""Burak"",
        ""dob"": ""1921-11-10T00:00:00+00:00""
    },
    {
        ""Id"": ""2"",
        ""name"": ""Franta"",
        ""surname"": ""Dobrota"",
        ""dob"": ""1933-10-05T00:00:00+00:00""
    },
    {
        ""Id"": ""3"",
        ""name"": ""Milos"",
        ""surname"": ""Ovcacek"",
        ""dob"": ""1988-05-05T00:00:00+00:00""
    }
]";


JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

// I have to build my request manually
List<string> esRequest = new List<string>();

foreach (var jtoken in jArray)
{
    var jobj = (JObject)jtoken;
    jobj.Add("DbCreated", JToken.FromObject(DateTime.UtcNow));
    jobj.Add("DbCreatedBy", JToken.FromObject("authors name"));

    string id;
    // Ensure that Id is set even if we receive it in lowercase        
    if( jobj["Id"] == null)
    {
        if( jobj["id"] == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("missing Id");
        }

        id = jobj["id"].Value<string>();
    }
    else
    {
        id = jobj["Id"].Value<string>();
    }
                                
    string indexName = "people";

    esRequest.Add($"{{\"index\":{{\"_index\":\"{indexName}\",\"_id\":\"{id}\"}}}}");
    esRequest.Add(jobj.ToString(Formatting.None));
                
}


PostData pd = PostData.MultiJson(esRequest);
var llres = client.LowLevel.Bulk<BulkResponse>(pd);
```

Hope it helps someone.