# How to Index Json Data using NEST Client for Elastic Search?

Tags: c#, nest

I am trying to index json string file to Elastic Search using C# NEST library. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819542/index-json-document-using-elasticsearch-nest-c-sharp) which is related. But there is a syntax error at `.Index<string>`

```
var indexResponse = _elasticClient.LowLevel.Index<string>("index-name", "type-name", json);
```

The error is

> The type 'string' cannot be used as type parameter 'TResponse' in the
> generic type or method
> 'IElasticLowLevelClient.Index(string, string, PostData,
> IndexRequestParameters)'. There is no implicit reference conversion
> from 'string'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [low level client documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/elasticsearch-net-getting-started.html#_indexing)

```cs
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri($"http://localhost:9200"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
    
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var person = @"{ ""first_name"": ""Russ"", ""last_name"": ""Cam"" }";

var indexResponse = client.LowLevel.Index<StringResponse>("people", "1", person);
string responseString = indexResponse.Body;
```